# How do I get handle to current fragment from activity object?

Tags: android, fragment

I do not have an ID or a Tag of the fragment that is loaded. Is there a way to get a handle to the fragment using FragmentManager ? I tried using addOnBackStackChangedListener but it does not even get triggered.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you not use any TAG or Id it will possible by iterate your **getSupportFragmentManage**r.

```
public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null){
        for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
            if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```